# How can I use one javascript object on many pages?

Tags: javascript, object, global

I want to add properties to an object and pass that object to another page.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking at [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage)?

Comment: he answered his own question @Jack hahah :P He posted for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. I would combine the functions in a namespace;
2. you don't need Base64 encoding, since `encodeURIComponent()` will suffice;
3. This is not suitable for large objects, you would need `localStorage` for that;
4. Your code had a few gotchas, such as when an href already contains a `?`;

I've reworked it like so:

```
DataTransferService = {
  sendToUrl: function(obj, url, name) {
    var value = JSON.stringify(obj);

    name = name || 'data';

    return url + (url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&') + name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value);
  },
  receiveFromCurrentUrl: function(name) {
    return receiveFromUrl(window.location.href, name);
  },
  receiveFromUrl: function(url, name) {
    var value;

    name = name || 'data';
    url = url || window.location.href;


    if ((value = this.getUrlParameter(name, url)) !== null) {
      return JSON.parse(value);
    }
  },
  getUrlParameter:function(name, url) {
    var p, qs;

    if ((p = url.indexOf('?')) === -1) {
      return null;
    }

    qs = url.substr(p + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0, len = qs.length; i != len; ++i) {
      var pair = qs[i].split('=');
      if (pair[0] === name) {
        return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
};
```

To use:

```
var obj = {
    a: 123,
    b: 456,
    c: [1, 3, 5]
};

var url = DataTransferService.sendToUrl(obj, '/path/to/page');
// "/path/to/page?data=..."
location = url;
```

On the receiving page:

```
var obj = DataTransferService.receiveFromCurrentUrl();
// work with obj here
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions to put in your global js file..

```
function GotoPage(relUrl) {
  var json = JSON.stringify({param1:val1, param2:val2});
  window.location.href = relUrl.concat('?data=').concat(Base64.encode(json));
}

function GetUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

Assume we're navigating from page1 to page2.. in page2's .js file you'll write:

```
var base64data = GetUrlVars()['data']
var jsondata = Base64.decode(base64data)
var data = JSON.parse(data);
var param1 = data.param1;
//do something with the objects properties
```

For the `Base64` implementation see: [How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript)

Comment: If you want to keep your url clean you could use a cookie.

Comment: Keep in mind this will fail if you want to put functions in your objects, since you're serializing the object as JSON and JSON only supports data.

Comment: nice effort, but not ideal. how about url limit? so, u giving up on big objects? I would go for local storage